# How to use a Vuejs web component as an input element in a none-vue web app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, web-component

I created a vuejs web component with `VueCli3`, the final compiled component looks like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="./my-lib.js"></script>

<my-lib></my-lib>
```

This web component simply creates a hidden input with some value. when I inspect it in the browser:

```
<my-lib>
    #shadow-root (open)
        <style type="text/css">....</style>
        <div data-v-1ca2f958="" id="app">
           <input type="hidden" name="my_input" value="some value">
        </div>
</my-lib>
```

I want to use this inside a `form` in a none-vue page alongside with other inputs, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/test.php">
   <input type="text" name="title" value="foo">
   <my-lib></my-lib>
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Now the problem is when I submit the form, only `title` parameter appears in the backend, the `my_input` param does not exist!

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

> When you use web component with shadow DOM, the input elements within shadow DOM are not submitted with traditional form submission. Read here for [more details](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/187).

In general, the only option is to introduce some JavaScript to submit your forms. The simple one I can think of is using [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) when the submit event is triggered and then manually introspecting all the custom elements.

```
function onSubmit() {


    const form = document.querySelector("form");

    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let x of form.elements) {
        formData.append(x.name,  x.value);
    }

    const customField = form.querySelector("my-lib");

    // Some way to access the custom form field's value
    formData.append("custom-field-name", customField.customValue);

    // Submit now
    // Write code to submit form using XHR or Fetch API
}
```

To save some keystrokes you can avoid the for loop as you can create `FormData` using existing form:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const formData = new FormData(form);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) 

Do I have to send data via `Ajax` ?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki, Use `XHR` or `Fetch` API!